# Double sum and zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, riemann-zeta

This is a personal research that came to an end , since the results were not those which were being anticipated. I was unable to come up with a solution therefore I post the topic here:

Prove (it certainly holds because it was checked on a computer) that the following identity holds:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^2}=\zeta(2)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left ( 2n-1 \right )^2}-\zeta(4)$$

wheras $\zeta$ represents the zeta function defined as $\displaystyle \zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}, \;\; \mathfrak{Re}(s)>1 $. Of course both values of $\zeta$ appearing here are known. For complete of sakeness i quote them :

$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}, \;\; \zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$$

Now, one can also see (not trivial ) that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2 \sinh^2 \pi n}=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^2} -\frac{\pi^2}{60}$$

This equation also holds (checked by computer). The following result was extracted by using the known formulae $\displaystyle \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z+n}=\frac{\pi}{\tan \pi z}$ and the known (?)  Fourier series:
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sinh^2 \pi z}=\frac{1}{\pi^2 z}+\frac{4z^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( z^2+k^2 \right )^2}-\frac{2}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^2+k^2} $$

Of course the last sum at the last equation can easily be computed via residues. What remains now is the proof for the first equation in the post. No-one can guarantee that is going to be an easy task.

---

Some comments:

**1.** I came across the identity on a book. I checked the validity with a computer and yes it does hold.

**2.** I have ckecked enough books to see if there is in there somewhere , but unfortunately it was not. So, I speculate that it is not that famous.

**3.** It can also be linked with other sums (single or double). Unfortunately I don't have my papers in front of me in order to write them down. So, i think it is an interseting identity.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: "it certainly holds because it was checked on a computer": have you ever heard of the law of small numbers? :)

Comment: @Leon Aragones: No.. I have not.. By that way I would like to inform that I corrected a typo in my post.

Comment: See the formula $(38)$ at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleSeries.html) for a more general formula (the generic term is "lattice sums").

Comment: @Tolaso Take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers) article.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni So, what basically you are saying here is that this sum actually relates to Beta Diriclet? Well, wow! Yes, one way it should.. because that alternating sum evaluates to $G$ (catalan constant) which is actually $\beta(2)$. Sounds interesting.. However I'm interested for a proof here... since all efforts failed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's consider the double sum over all $\,(n,k)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\,$ except the origin $(0,0)$ :
$$\tag{1}S(s):=\sum_{(n,k)\neq (0,0)}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^s}=4\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^s}+\zeta(2\,s)\right)$$
This is a "Lorenz–Hardy sum" (ref. Lorenz L. $1871$ "Bidrag tiltalienes theori" and Hardy G. H. $1919$ "On some deﬁnite integral considered by Mellin" in his Collected papers vol $7$).

### Analytical method

The [Mellin transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) of a function $f$ is defined by :
$$\tag{2}\{\mathcal{M}f\}(s):=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}f(t)\;dt$$
applied to $\;f:t\mapsto e^{\large{-mt}}\;$ and from the definition of the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) gives :
$$\tag{3}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\left(m \right)^s}=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\,e^{-m\,t}\;dt$$
Supposing that $\Re(s)>1$ we may rewrite our double-sum as :
\begin{align}
\Gamma(s)\,S(s)&=\sum_{(n,k)\neq (0,0)}\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^s}\\
&=\sum_{(n,k)\neq (0,0)}\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\,e^{-(n^2+k^2)\,t}\;dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\sum_{(n,k)\neq (0,0)}\,e^{-(n^2+k^2)\,t}\;dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\,e^{-n^2\,t}\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\,e^{-k^2\,t}-1\right)\;dt\\
\tag{4}&=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\left(\theta_3(0,e^{-t})^2-1\right)\;dt\\
\end{align}
i.e. the Mellin transform of $\,f:t\mapsto \theta_3(0,e^{-t})^2-1\,$ where the [Jacobi theta function $\theta_3$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) is defined by (in this answer we will implicitly suppose that $z=0$ and $q=e^{-t}$) :
$$\tag{5}\theta_3(z,q):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}e^{2niz}$$

In $1829$ Jacobi published his deep elliptic functions book "Fundamenta nova theoriae functionum ellipticarum" where he obtained numerous identities [including the formula $4$) of page $103$](https://archive.org/stream/fundamentanovat00jacogoog#page/n118/mode/2up) :
$$\tag{6}\theta_3(0,q)^2=\frac {2\,K}{\pi}=1+4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1+q^{2n}}$$
($K$ is the [Complete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) but we won't use it here)

The series at the right of $(6)$ is a [Lambert series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertSeries.html). The expansion of the denominator in power series and substitution of the double-sum in $(4)$ gives :

\begin{align}
\Gamma(s)\,S(s)&=4\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m q^n\,q^{2mn}\;dt\\
&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-n(2m+1)t}\;dt\\
&=4\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^m \frac{\Gamma(s)}{(n(2m+1))^s}\\
&=4\,\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{n^s}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(2m+1)^s}\\
&=4\,\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)\,\beta(s)\\
\\
&\text{so that }\\
\\
\tag{7}\sum_{(n,k)\neq (0,0)}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^s}&=4\,\zeta(s)\,\beta(s),\quad\Re(s)>1\\
&\text{and}\\
\tag{8}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left ( n^2+k^2 \right )^s}&=\zeta(s)\,\beta(s)-\zeta(2s),\quad\Re(s)>1\\
\\\end{align}

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$with $\beta$ the [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).

This powerful method allows to deduce many closed forms of [lattice sums](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LatticeSum.html) from the known [theta identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

I'll try to add one (or more) alternative derivations when time allows...

**References** :

- Glasser and Zucker 1980 "Lattice sums" In "Theoretical Chemistry, Advances and Perspectives Vol $5$".
- Borwein and Borwein 1987 "Pi and the AGM".
- Borwein, Glasser, McPhedran, Wan and Zucker 2013 ["Lattice Sums Then and Now"](http://www.carma.newcastle.edu.au/LatticeSums/) (and older papers from these authors)

Comment: Really excellent explanations!

Comment: Thanks @yarchik! You may be interested by the deeper algebraic solutions provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28415/a-double-series-yielding-riemanns-zeta) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348599/l-function-easiest-way-to-see-the-following-sum). Excellent continuation,