# Series involving $\sum_{m,n}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{2k}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta, modular-forms

The series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \zeta (2k)z^{2k}$$
(where $\zeta$ is the zeta function) has a non-zero radius of convergence (in $z$). This led me to the following question:

Let
$$C_k=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^{2k}}$$
where $k$ is an integer $\ge 1$. Does
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty C_k z^{4k}$$
have a non-zero radius of convergence as well?

In fact, $C_k$ is "almost" the Eisenstein series (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein_series) of weight $4k$ evaluated at $i$ (known to converge absolutely), with the summand replaced by absolute value:
$$C_k=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{|m+ni|^{4k}}.$$

I tried to build on the analogy with the zeta function. Using the fact that $m^2+n^2\ge n^2$, I obtained
$$C_k\le \zeta (4k)+\sum_{m=1}^\infty \zeta (4k)$$
but, unfortunately, this doesn't lead anywhere.

Comment: $C_k$ may be obtained using this [lattice sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1119472/21783)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest approach is to note that $C_k$ is decreasing in $k$. As $C_1$ is finite, we have
$$ \left \lvert \sum_{k \geq 1} C_k z^k \right \rvert
\leq \sum_{k \geq 1} \lvert C_k \rvert \lvert z \rvert^k
\leq C_1 \sum_{k \geq 1} \lvert z \rvert^k \leq C_1 \frac{\lvert z \rvert}{1 - \lvert z \rvert},$$
assuming that $\lvert z \rvert < 1$ so that the geometric series converges.