# Proving double sum $\sum _{a=1}^{\infty }\sum _{b=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{a+b}}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^s} $

Tags: calculus, summation

I have see this formula in Wolframe Alpha Double series's documentation, but what is the procces of proving?
$$\sum _{a=1}^{\infty }\sum _{b=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{a+b}}{\left(a^2+b^2\right)^s}=\eta \left(2s\right)-\eta \left(s\right)\beta \left(s\right)
$$
Where
$$ \beta \left(s\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\left(2n-1\right)^s}$$

$$\eta \left(s\right)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

Comment: What is $\beta (s)$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh, dirichlet beta function

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: $\beta(s)$ is better understood as $L(s,\chi_4)$. Did you prove that $\sum_{a,b\in \Bbb{Z}^2- (0,0)} (a^2+b^2)^{-s}=4 \zeta(s)L(s,\chi_4)$ ?

Comment: For the non-alternating version of the sum (as in the comment above), see [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28415), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1348599), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1108246), etc. Then you can follow any of these approaches to handle the present (alternating) case. (I would post an answer myself, but your question is about to be qualified as MCoOD.)